# What is LinearLayoutICS?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I noticed when making a LinearLayout in XML in Android Studio there was an element called LinearLayoutICS (android.support.v7.internal.widget.LinearLayoutICS).

I tried to do some searching, and I can't figure out what extra functionality it provides when comparing with a good ol' LinearLayout. Looks like maybe something to do with dividers...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearLayoutICS` backports the ability to define dividers in a `LinearLayout` for pre-Honeycomb devices (i.e., API < 11).

It is useful only if you have defined an `android:minSdkVersion` between 7 and 10 in your AndroidManifest.xml file. If you are targetting only API >= 11, just use the standard LinearLayout. If you are targetting API < 7, LinearLayoutICS is not an option, because the appcompat library it is part of requires at least an API level of 7 (hence the "v7" in the package name).

Comment: Actually, it can't show the dividers well on some cases. only via XML. However, if you wish to have it dynamically, you can check out this post I've made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547897/how-to-add-dividers-to-linearlayoutics/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.3_r1/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/LinearLayoutICS.java) is the source code for it. This class is a part of appcompat library, so I guess it is used to show dividers in ActionBar items. Not 100% sure though